# Convert a String to a Vector in Java

Tags: java, vector, converters

I have a function that has an output as a 4 character String like "1000". I need to convert this into a vector of dimension (4,1) in order to be able to make computation with matrices.
Any idea or help? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your question doesn't explain what you've done to try and solve the problem; it currently reads like a request for code. Please share your attempted implementation and explain how it fails to meet your requirements.

Comment: Why a `Vector`? Why not a `List`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = "1000";
Vector myVec = new Vector();

//Convert the string to a char array and then just add each char to the vector
char[] sChars = s.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
    myVec.add(sChars[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Vector<Character> v = new Vector<Character>(Arrays.asList(yourString.toCharArray()))
```

As stated by fge, a List would be at least as useful as a Vector:

```
List<Character> l = Arrays.asList(yourString.toCharArray())
```

Comment: Won't work. You can't have a primitive type as a type parameter.

Comment: My god, you're right. C# reflex. Corrected. Thx!